# Count unique values in objects within large JSON file with Python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have some rather large JSON files. Each contains thousands of objects within one (1) array. The JSONs are structured in the following format:

```
{
    "alert": [
    { "field1": "abc",
    "field2": "def",
    "field3": "xyz
},
{ "field1": null,
"field2": null,
"field3": "xyz",
},
...
...
]
```

What's the most efficient way to use Python and the json library to search through a JSON file, find the unique values in each object within the array, and count how many times they appear? E.g., search the array's "field3" objects for the value "xyz" and count how many times it appears. I tried a few variations based on existing solutions in StackOverflow, but they are not providing the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on PyPI turned up

- ijson 2.3 - Iterative JSON parser with a standard Python iterator interface
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson

Here's an example which should work for your data

```
import ijson

counts = {}
with file("data.json") as f:
    objects = ijson.items(f, 'alert.item')
    for o in objects:
        for k, v in o.items():
            field = counts.get(k,{})
            total = field.get(v,0)
            field[v] = total + 1
            counts[k] = field

import json
print json.dumps(counts, indent=2)
```

running this with your sample data in `data.json` produces

```
{
  "field2": {
    "null": 1, 
    "def": 1
  }, 
  "field3": {
    "xyz": 2
  }, 
  "field1": {
    "null": 1, 
    "abc": 1
  }
}
```

Note however that the `null` in your input was transformed into the string "null".

As a point of comparison, here is a [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) command which produces an equivalent result using `tostream`

```
 jq -M '
    reduce (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (
      {}
    ; ($p[2:]+[$v|tostring]) as $k
    | setpath($k; getpath($k)+1)
    )
' data.json
```